# Как с помощью псевдоэлемента добавить блок?

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. В этом коде (чтобы ссылка стала рабочей уберите пробелы до и посте точки) http://jsfiddle.net/mmnoyjoL/5/  у меня не получается добавить блок с помощью псевдоэлемента ::after. Оранжевый блок(размер 700*300) должен быть поверх синего(300*300). Поэтому я использовал z-index, а также у меня не выходит выровнять оранжевый блок по середине серого(основного контейнера). margin: auto; в данном случае не работает.

Подскажите каким образом можно реализовать это. Спасибо.

```css
.main{
 height: 500px;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 background-color: #c6c6c6;
}

.top{
 width: 700px;
 height: 300px;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #ffcb56;
 z-index: 1;
}

.under_top{
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #6a56ff;
 top: 50px;
 left: 450px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
 
 <div class="top"></div>
 <div class="under_top"></div>
 
</div>
```

Comment: в стилях не элемента `after`

Comment: чувак сам не знает что хочет

Comment: чувак знает что хочет. Просто не знает как это сделать

Answer (score 1):

Поменяйте стили оранжевого блока так:

```
.top{
    width: 700px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #ffcb56;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

А по поводу блока через `::after` не понял. Какой блок и куда.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div
{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background:red;
 position:relative;
 color:#fff;
}
div:after
{
 content:"вот так это делается";
 display:none;
 width:150px;
  padding:13px 20px;
 background:#ccc;
 background-size:100% 100%;
 position:absolute;
 right:-200px; top:0;
 transition:.5s;
}
div:hover:after{
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<div>Наведи на меня</div>
```

Это про `after`